# How to get a session's key with webapp2 and datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2, google-app-engine-python

I am trying to implement a 'remember me' feature on the login page.

This is the logic I have in mind: Store sessions in the datastore,
pass the session id/key to the client so that next time the user visits
the site, i get information from the datastore with the key the client has

I was about to do something like this:

```
class Session(ndb.Model):
    username = ndb.StringProperty()
    email = ndb.StringProperty()

if request.get('rememberme'):
    session = Session()
    session.email = 'john@doe.com'
    session.username = 'jon snow'
    key = session.put()
    # send `key` back to client and store in a cookie, so
    # when client visits the site again, get the session
    # values from the datastore 
    self.response.write(key.id())
```

But I'm using this snippet from the [docs](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/webapp2_extras/sessions.html#webapp2_extras.sessions.SessionStore) to handle my sessions:

```
class BaseHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

  def dispatch(self):
    self.session_store = sessions.get_store(request=self.request)
    try:
      webapp2.RequestHandler.dispatch(self)
    finally:
      self.session_store.save_sessions(self.response)

  @webapp2.cached_property
  def session(self):
    return self.session_store.get_session(name='foo', backend='datastore')
```

This too ,inserts data into the datastore under the 'Session' Kind.
So it feels like I'd be doing redudant work if I were to manually store sessions in the datastore as well.

When using webapp2's session with datastore as the backend, how can I know that session's id/key?

Comment: Why do you need to know the key? You can get the data directly in your handler with `self.session['whatever']`.

Comment: to retrieve it from datastore the next time the user visits the app. before i can do `session['whatever']`, i need to get it from the datastore, preferably with a key stored in the client's cookie